# How to replace a specific text from a text file using python3

Tags: python, text

hello here i wont to replace a specific text from a file but the problem is that i did't know what is that text it could be anything example here is a text file

```
hello_my_name_is name hello_my_age_is age
hello_i_am_from place
```

here i just wont to replace a age and name but it should be anything i did't know what is it and i did't wont to change any other text there i have already created a python file which can do that but it is not working properly here it is

```
with open('data.txt' , 'r') as re:
    all_data = re.read()
    all_data = all_data.replace('hello_my_name_is' , 'hello_my_name_is python')
    all_data = all_data.replace('hello_my_age_is' , 'hello_my_age_is 102')

with open('data.txt' , 'w') as op:
    op.write(all_data)
    print(all_data)
```

here the problem is that the old data is there it did't change or remove how to replace or remove that data in that file ??? and also i did't wont to change anything and also i did't know about place it also should be anything

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. The result prints out a new first line: "hello_my_name_is python name hello_my_age_is 102 age", and that line also exists in an updated version of `data.txt`.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to do `all_data = all_data.replace(' name ' , ' python ')` instead? And similar for `age`. That may get you into problems with word separators, since `age` has (probably) a newline instead of a space on its right.

Comment: but the problem is i don't know what is name like it could be python or name or any thing i don't know what is name here and also this would apply for age also here